# AutoMapper Exception

Tags: automapper

This is a first time i have been bogged down like this by automapper. I am trying to map a result set returned by the stored procedure to my entity. L2S has the result set available, it is one row for my current test, can by multiple. Usually automaper exception is thrown when a return type is nullable if not properly handled. I have left it as is and also changed it to some value but in both cases i am still getting the exception. I am missing some thing very basic here but can't put my hands on it. Need second pair of eyes... Thanks.

**Code Call**

```
var annualReportOutreachEditionResult = ClientsContext.AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGet(fice, reportYear).ToList();
            if (annualReportOutreachEditionResult != null)
            {
                annualReportOutreachEditionDetail = Mapper.Map<List<AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult>, List<AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail>>(annualReportOutreachEditionResult);
```

**AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail Entity**

```
public class AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail
    {



        public string Edition { get; set; }


        public DateTime MailDate { get; set; }


        public string CardId { get; set; }


    }
```

**AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult L2S Entity**

```
public partial class AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult
    {

        private string _Edition;

        private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _MailDate;

        private string _CardId;

        public AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult()
        {
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Edition", DbType="VarChar(50)")]
        public string Edition
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Edition;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Edition != value))
                {
                    this._Edition = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_MailDate", DbType="Date")]
        public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> MailDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this._MailDate;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._MailDate != value))
                {
                    this._MailDate = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CardId", DbType="Char(9)")]
        public string CardId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._CardId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._CardId != value))
                {
                    this._CardId = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**MApping**

I have also checked/tested defaultvalue for date and my exception is still there. That is the only nullable type.

```
 public static void MapAnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult, AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail>()

                ;
        }
```

**Exception Details**

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Trying to map System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Nrccua.LinqToSql.AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult, Nrccua.LinqToSql, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Nrccua.BusinessEntities.AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail, Nrccua.BusinessEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
  Source=AutoMapper
  StackTrace:
       at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
       at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
       at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
       at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
       at Nrccua.LinqToSql.DataAccess.AnnualReportAccess.GetAnnualReportOutreachEditionDetails(String fice, String reportYear) in C:\Users\tahir\Documents\DATA\Projects\NrccuaWebSite\NrccuaWebSiteTahirj\Core\BusinessEntities\Nrccua.LinqToSql\DataAccess\AnnualReportAccess.cs:line 211
       at Nrccua.Repositories.AnnualReportRepository.GetAnnualReportOutreachEditionDetails(String fice, String reportYear) in C:\Users\tahir\Documents\DATA\Projects\NrccuaWebSite\NrccuaWebSiteTahirj\Core\Repositories\Nrccua.Repositories\AnnualReportRepository.cs:line 199
       at RepositoryTests.AnnualReportTest.GetOutreachDetailsTest() in C:\Users\tahir\Documents\DATA\Projects\NrccuaWebSite\NrccuaWebSiteTahirj\Core\Tests\RepositoryTests\AnnualReportTest.cs:line 55
  InnerException: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
       Message=Trying to map Nrccua.LinqToSql.AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult to Nrccua.BusinessEntities.AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
       Source=AutoMapper
       StackTrace:
            at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
            at AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumerableMapperBase`1.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
            at AutoMapper.Mappers.CollectionMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
            at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
       InnerException: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
            Message=Trying to map Nrccua.LinqToSql.AnnualReportOutreachEditionInfoGetResult to Nrccua.BusinessEntities.AnnualReportOutreachEditionDetail.
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
            Source=AutoMapper
            StackTrace:
                 at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem at my end, I forgot to add the definition for my mapper method. Fixed.